# Old values get duplication in For each loop

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting values from Firebase. But the problem occur when i try to add values in array previous values get repeated. Can anyone tell me how can i put values in Array . i want to show those values in recyclerview.

Code :

```
    bookCollection
            .get().addOnSuccessListener {
                booksSnapshot->
                if (!booksSnapshot.isEmpty){
                    var booksArray = arrayListOf<Book>()
                    for (bookSnapshot in booksSnapshot.documents){
                        val hashmap = bookSnapshot.data
                        hashmap?.put("id", bookSnapshot.id)
                        bookCollection.document(bookSnapshot.id).collection("pages")
                                .get().addOnSuccessListener {
                                    pagesSnapshot->
                                    hashmap?.put("page_count", pagesSnapshot.documents.size)
                                    val bookData = Gson().toJson(hashmap)
                                    val book = Gson().fromJson<Book>(bookData, Book::class.java)
                                    booksArray.add(book)
                                }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Log for array :

```
E/books: [co.myapp.myapplication.Book@d6f7f62]
E/books: [co.myapp.myapplication.Book@d6f7f62, co.syntags.myapplication.Book@93c49b0]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to clear your ForEach loop `booksArray` before adding new values.**
Because when you are adding new values that is added as the next items in your array.

Use `booksArray.clear()` Before adding new values where you are using booksArray.add(book)

Replace this  `var booksArray = arrayListOf<Book>()` With `var booksArray = ArrayList<Book>()`

Comment: it clears the whole array which makes my old values removed from array. I don't think it's perfect solution for users

Answer (score 0):

in main class (List add) :-

(Yourlistname).add(new yourpojoname(your value));

in PoJo class :-
create constructor :-

--> public constructorName(String s) { (Your value) = s; }

note :- yourpojoname == constructorName

Comment: can you send me in proper way i can't understand it.

Comment: In your case Book is pojo then you can try this


--> bookArray.add(new Book(book));

So it will create new constructor and you have to write in that constructor like this..

--> this.book = book ;

Note :- this.book is your pojo variable where you will get value from pojo.